# Sending JSON's through HTTP Request, but the Response is NULL

Tags: java, json, post, httprequest, outputstream

I need to send some JSONs to another application of mine, for it to store them in a database. 
My problem is that the other app keeps getting NULL parameters.
Here is my "sender" app:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Employee> employeeQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            byte[] array = new byte[7]; // length is bounded by 7
            new Random().nextBytes(array);
            String generatedString = new String(array, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            long id = new Random().nextLong() & 0xffffffffL;
            employeeQueue.add(new Employee(id, generatedString));
        }


        try {
            while (!employeeQueue.isEmpty()) {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(employeeQueue.remove());

                URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/postgressApp/createEmp");
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
                con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                con.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
                try {
                    json.write(osw);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                osw.flush();
                osw.close();    
                os.close();

                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    String responseLine = null;
                    while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(responseLine.trim());
                    }
                    System.out.println("Response from server: " + response.toString());
                }

            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The "receiver app is a simple spring-boot app waiting for "POST" Requests in a Controller and sending the content of the JSON to a database.

Comment: Convert JsonObject into byte array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working for me.
Use Gson for parsing Java Dto to JSON type. download com.google.code.gson.jar-2.2.4 version. 
In your code, I got the issue with parsing.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Employee> employeeQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        byte[] array = new byte[7]; // length is bounded by 7
        new Random().nextBytes(array);
        String generatedString = new String(array, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        long id = new Random().nextLong() & 0xffffffffL;
        employeeQueue.add(new Employee(id, generatedString));
    }


    try {
        while (!employeeQueue.isEmpty()) {

          Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();  


                String jsonEmp = gson.toJson(employeeQueue.remove());

          //  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(employeeQueue.remove());

            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/postgressApp/createEmp");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            con.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
            try {
                 osw.write(jsonEmp);
               // json.write(osw);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();    
            os.close();

            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                String responseLine = null;
                while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(responseLine.trim());
                }
                System.out.println("Response from server: " + response.toString());
            }

        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i found out the problem was that my model from "sending" didn't have the same name for the parameters as the model from the "receiving" application.

Comment: Do you have any ideea how can i implement this code to send faster ?

Comment: If you're using spring then use rest template.RestTemplete is fast and we can implement easily, It returns understandable error code.                         
Otherwise, use This one only. I am suggested to send the list of data at a time if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Convert JsonObject into byte array then write

byte [] outputBytes=json.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")

OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
os.write(outputBytes);

Comment: I replace my os with your variation, but i still get a NULL response. This is the error from the "receiver" application : "java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into employee(employeeId, employeeName ) values(NULL,NULL) was aborted: ERROR: null value in column "employeeid" violates not-null constraint"